# Set scrollspeed of Primefaces' scrollpanel

Tags: primefaces

Is there a posibility to set scrollspeed of Primefaces' ScrollPanel? Scrollspeed of Scrollpanel in "native" mode is ok but not in "deafult" mode.

I'm using Primefaces 3.2-SNAPSHOT, JSF 2.1 and Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Primefaces 3.2 but on 6.0 you can do this:

```
<p:scrollPanel id="scheduleDayViewScrollPanel" styleClass="static-width">
...
</p:scrollPanel>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#scheduleDayViewScrollPanel").jScrollPane({mouseWheelSpeed: 50});
     });
</script>
```

Primefaces 6.0 uses jScrollPane - v2.0.19 - 2013-11-16 
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/